# Regular expression for infix to postfix

Tags: c#, regex, data-structures

I came across following line while going through code that converts infix expression to postfix.

`string pattern = @"(?<=[^\\.a-zA-Z\\d])|(?=[^\\.a-zA-Z\\d])"`

Could not quite get what "\\" in above regular expression is worth while converting something like `((a+(b*(f/c)))-e) to abfc/*+e-`

Comment: It is the escape sequencing characters.

Comment: Does this pattern even work? (for me its only empty matches) can you add the code that is doing the conversion?

Comment: Each of those backslashes becomes a literal backslash in the regex, which I'm pretty sure is not what the original author intended.  You need to either drop one backslash from each pair, or remove the `@` before the opening quote.  Google `"verbatim string"` to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

When the value gets assigned to the string, it will become `\.` which means you are literally looking for a `.`

In regular expression `.` matches any character, where as here, `\.` will match a `.` character literally.

Comment: Actually, the regex will look exactly like it does in his string literal.  Notice the `@` in front of the opening quote?  He's using a C# verbatim string literal, which doesn't recognize any escape sequences; backslash is just another character.  And that's why it doesn't work: too many backslashes.